# Links to resources for mobile devices only

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

### problem

Many sites (like Wikipedia) offer versions of their pages made for fullscreen-devices, and for each of those pages they offer a second version with the same content, but with a special reduced layout for mobile devices with a smaller screen.

There are many techniques to create and deliver those versions, one of them is to create different URIs (URI = Unique Resource Identifier = string starting with “http://”) for the same content, which will deliver different styles for the same content.

When users with mobile devices navigate to one of those sites that are not optimized for them (like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device) they will be redirected to the version for mobile devices, which is in this example is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device (see the “**m.**” between “en.” and “wikipedia”?)

But the reverse behavior will not occur. When you follow a link to a version for mobile devices, you always get the mobile version, even when you use a 27" desktop monitor, which looks pretty weird.

When ever users of mobile devices post links here on StackExchange, they will post a link to the version for mobile devices, because they have no other link. But this is suboptimal for users of fullscreen devices.

### solution = feature request

Therefor I suggest, to automatically replace URIs that link to mobile-only pages by their all-device-counterpart (which means for links to wikipedia: delete the “m.” that precedes “wikipedia.org”) as soon as the link is posted. Because then everybody who follows this link is happy:

- the widescreen-user gets the widescreen version
- the mobile user will be redirected to the version that is optimized for him.
- nobody needs to worry about if he/she posted the correct link.

Comment: Another option: edit such links so they don't point to the mobile URI?

Comment: @Oded: Who is responsible for editing? The user who posted it? He/she don't see a problem, so he/she is not aware of it. The user who is wondering, why the liked page has this funny layout? Maybe he also is not aware of the problem. Also he still left stackexchange by following the link. Why should he come back? Or should there be some kind of “StackExchange-officer” who's job is to clean up links? No, I think an automated solution would be the best.

Comment: Well, **anyone** can edit. That's one the point of Stack Exchange sites. You can edit (or suggest an edit). Anonymous users can suggest edits. And if they are good, they will be accepted.

Comment: @Oded: Yes, anyone can, but not everybody does it. It is nobody's job. Nobody is responsible for it. So many of those links stay unchanged. If you implement a simple automatic replacement *.m.wikipedia.org/ -> .wikipedia.org/* then none of those links will be forgotten.